# Could not get React-Native-WebRTC to work

Tags: react-native, webrtc, feathersjs

Need some help running through my codes to make WebRTC work. I am just trying to make a call from one device to the other.  Realise I'm not throughly understanding WebRTC. My app crashes when the answer is emitted back.

The socket/emitter I am working with is actually
[FeathersJS](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/events.html#custom-events) services. It is serving as my backend, whenever I need to emit, I send a create service and in my backend, feathersJS emit a customEmitter `['offer' 'answer' 'ice-candidate']`. Although I am able to receive all emitted events, I am unable to get WebRTC to work. The below are my React-native code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  View, SafeAreaView, Button, StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  RTCPeerConnection,
  RTCSessionDescription,
  RTCView,
  mediaDevices,
} from 'react-native-webrtc';
import ContextApp from '../../context/contextApp';
import FeathersApp, { Services } from '../../Feathers';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#313131',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100%',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  rtcview: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '40%',
    width: '80%',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  rtc: {
    width: '80%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  toggleButtons: {
    width: '100%',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
  },
});

const VideoCallPage = ( props: any ) => {
  const { userId } = props;
  const { authState } = useContext(ContextApp);
  const callService = FeathersApp.service(Services.CALL);

  const [callAlert, setCallAlert] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [offerData, setOfferData] = useState<any>();
  const configuration = {"iceServers": [{"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]};

  const localPC = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
  const [localStream, setLocalStream] = useState<any>();
  const [remoteStream, setRemoteStream] = useState<any>();

  const sendToPeer = (messageType: any, payload: any) => {
    callService.create({
      callType: messageType,
      sdp: payload,
      caller: authState._id,
      answerer: userId,
      candidate: payload,
    })
  }
  const createOffer = async () => {
    const offer = await localPC.createOffer();
    await localPC.setLocalDescription(offer).then(() => console.log('local offer succeeded'));
    sendToPeer('offer', localPC.localDescription);
  }
  const createIceCandidate = () => {
    localPC.onicecandidate = e => {
      try {
        console.log('localPC icecandidate:', e.candidate);
        if (e.candidate) {
          sendToPeer('ice-candidate', e.candidate)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Error adding remotePC iceCandidate: ${err}`);
      }
    };
  }
  const startCall = async () => {
    console.log('start call funtion')
    const newStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: false,
    });
    setLocalStream(newStream);
    createIceCandidate()
    createOffer();
  };
  const recieveCall = async (incoming: any) => {
    console.log('accepting call');
    await localPC.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(incoming.sdp));

    const answer = await localPC.createAnswer();
    await localPC.setLocalDescription(answer).then(() => console.log('localPC desc succeeded'));

    sendToPeer('answer', localPC.localDescription);
    createIceCandidate();
    localPC.addStream(localStream);

    localPC.onaddstream = e => {
      console.log('remotePC tracking with ', e);
      if (e.stream && remoteStream !== e.stream) {
        console.log('RemotePC received the stream', e.stream);
        setRemoteStream(e.stream);
      }
    };
  };
const recieveAnswer = (payload: any) => {
  console.log('recieved answer: ', payload.candidate.sdp)
  localPC.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(payload.candidate.sdp));
  localPC.onaddstream = e => {
    if (e.stream && remoteStream !== e.stream) {
      console.log('RemotePC received the stream', e.stream);
      setRemoteStream(e.stream);
    }
  };
}
  // alert for any calls
  useEffect(() => {
    callService.on('ice-candidate', (incoming: any) => {
      localPC.addIceCandidate(incoming.data.sdp);
      localPC.addStream(localStream);
    });
    callService.on('offer', async (payload: any) => {
      if (payload.data.answerer === authState._id) {
        const newStreamForReciever = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          video: false,
        });
        setLocalStream(newStreamForReciever);
        setOfferData(await payload.data);
        setCallAlert(true);
      }
    });
    callService.on('answer', async (payload: any) => {
      if (payload.data.answerer === authState._id) {
        console.log(userId, 'answered')
        recieveAnswer(await payload.data);
      }
    });
    // return (() => {
    //   callService.removeAllListener('ice-candidate');
    //   callService.removeAllListener('offer');
    //   callService.removeAllListener('answer');
    // })
  }, [callService]);

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      {!localStream && <Button title="Click to start CALL stream" onPress={startCall} />}
      {callAlert && <Button title="Answer Call" onPress={() => recieveCall(offerData)} />}

      {localStream && (
        <View style={styles.toggleButtons}>
        </View>
      )}

      <View style={styles.rtcview}>
        {localStream && <RTCView style={styles.rtc} streamURL={localStream.toURL()} />}
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rtcview}>
        {remoteStream && <RTCView style={styles.rtc} streamURL={remoteStream.toURL()} />}
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  )
};

export default VideoCallPage;
```

What is it that I am missing out??
Any guidance you can provide is greatly appreciated!